How can i create a same blured view by using a swiftUI and its materials (.ultraThinMaterial.regular.thickmaterial) and etc
How to recreate the same blurred view then one which says McDonalds by using purely swiftUI i believe materials modifier can help me somehow but do i need to recreate it with opacity or no? I want to do it without a library

Even a thin material background provides a heavy blur. It also provides a lighter shade (in light mode) and darker shade (in dark mode).
If you always want the effect to be dark then you can enforce dark mode:

the modifier .preferredColorScheme(.dark) will apply dark mode to the parent view and all child content
to enforce dark mode on just the local view, use .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) instead (ref. this answer).

ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Image(systemName: "ladybug.fill")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(20)
        .background(.red)
    Text("Hello")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .padding(50)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.regularMaterial)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        .padding(10)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
}



Thank you so much for your reply but the example which u attached its a bit of more light i need it to be a bit more darker shade

@NursultanYelemessov Updated again with a better way of enforcing dark mode

I mean its not exactly what i wanted but i ll take thanks man! I ll mark your answer as the correct one. Cause i think the way how i want it to be is a lot of hustle for nothing.
